# pytorch where is Embedding "max_norm" implemented?

Tags: pytorch

The "embedding" class documentation https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html says

`max_norm (float, optional) – If given, will renormalize the embedding vectors to have a norm lesser than this before extracting.`

1) In my model, I use this embedding class as a parameter, not just as an input (the model learns the embedding.) In this case, I assume every time when updates happen, the embedding gets renormalized, not only when it's initialized. Is my understanding correct?

2) I wanted to confirm 1) by looking at the source, but I couldn't find the implementation in pytorch embedding class. https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/nn/modules/sparse.html 
Can someone point me to the `max_norm` implementation?

Comment: 1) You can test it; 2) `max_norm` is an option so the implementations you might want to know are those of the functions you are calling after setting the option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you see `forward` function in Embedding class [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/nn/modules/sparse.html#Embedding), there is a reference to [torch.nn.functional.embedding](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/nn/functional.html#embedding) which uses embedding_renorm_ which is in the cpp documentation [here](https://pytorch.org/cppdocs/api/function_namespaceat_1a2e24b3abb0f34e847a01ad14e187c0c8.html) which means it is a cpp implementation. Some github search on pytorch repo pointed to this files ([1](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/b14f2e899c92f541644e393b2513aa60aeb9196f/aten/src/ATen/native/Embedding.cpp), [2](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/03c06ec93db58e444df13e075a74297a9f9a9524/aten/src/ATen/native/native_functions.yaml)).

Answer to 1 is yes. Answer to 2 is above.

Comment: The link is now broken.  I wonder why it's so difficult to locate the C++ source code for torch.